# Compare two Arrays and find the index where the arrays dont match anymore in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, int

i have the following question.
I need to implement a Method to compare two Arrays and find the first index on which the elements of given arrays do not match.
I have tried the following code but its kinda weak:

```
public int UnmatchedElementsOnIndex(int[] x, int[] y) {

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
            if (x[i] == y[j]) {
                // value is contained in both arrays
            }
            // otherwise not
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong. You can do with a single loop and some if statements.

Comment: I tought of using an extra variable that counts ++ if an unmatching element is found, but i don't know how to implement this

Comment: Try it yourself first instead of looking for answers from SO score seekers :P. You can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [java.lang.Arrays.mistmatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#mismatch(int%5B%5D,int%5B%5D)) method to find the index of the first mismatch between two arrays of the same type. If no mismatch is found, it returns -1.

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] b = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3 };

        
Arrays.mismatch(a, b); // will return 5
```

This method will perform substantially better than custom code, since it compares data in the arrays in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public int UnmatchedElementsOnIndex(int[] x, int[] y) {

        // Also check for the list length
        if(x.length < y.length)
          return x.length;
        else if(y.length < x.length)
          return y.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
              if(x[i] != y[i]) return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

It will return -1 if all elements in both arrays are the same, othewise return the first index when array not contain the same element in the same position.

Comment: Can cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException while looping.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to scan through each element in the arrays. Then determine which element is not matching. The following is an one way to implement this.

```
public int UnmatchedElementsOnIndex(int[] x, int[] y) {
    int index=-1;
    //lengths should be equal. If not, we can't compare arrays
    if(x.length!=y.length){
        return -2;
    }   
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] != y[i]) {
            index=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    //returns -1, if all the elements are equal
    return index;
}
```

Comment: That helped! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a[]={15,5,85,7};
        int b[] = {25,5,85,8};
        UnmatchedElementsOnIndex(a,b);
    }
    public static void UnmatchedElementsOnIndex(int[] x, int[] y) {
        int index=-1;
        int[] array = new int[x.length];
        int n=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] != y[i]) {
                array[n]=i;
                n++;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int UnmatchedElementsOnIndex(int[] x, int[] y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length && i < y.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] != y[i]) {
            return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```